# How can i restore the default set of fonts in my windows 10 fonts folder?

Tags: windows, fonts

My windows 10 (64 bit) font folder is cluttered with fonts from over the years... I now understand that certain font managers can temporarily install fonts which is exactly what i need to do occasionally. Is there an way i can restore only the default windows system font set to the font folder.

I was thinking about booting from a win PE enabled iso, deleting the fonts within the windows font folder and then pasting the default set of fonts from another laptop, then boot into windows, run a registry cleaner to remove all unlinked font references....will it work ? or is there another more reasonable way?

Answer (score -1):

please try if the following methods were helpful.

**Option 1 Restore Default Font Settings in Font Settings**

1. Open the C:\Windows\Fonts folder in File Explorer (Win+E). You could also open the Control Panel (icons view), and click/tap on the Fonts icon to open the Fonts folder.
2. Click/tap on the Font settings link at the top left in the Fonts folder.
3. Click/tap on the Restore default font settings button. (see screenshots below)
4. You can now close the Fonts folder window if you like.

**Option 2 Restore Default Font Settings using a REG file**

**To restore defaults for fonts in Windows 10, apply the following Registry tweak:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management]
"Auto Activation Mode"=dword:00000001
"InstallAsLink"=dword:00000000
"Inactive Fonts"=-
"Active Languages"=-
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management\Auto Activation Languages]
```

**Save the contents of the Registry tweak to a REG file, then double-click on it to apply.**